# What is your approach for querying Cassandra with Spark (in R or Python)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, sparklyr

I am working with about a TB of data stored in Cassandra and trying to query it using Spark and R (could be Python).

My preference for querying the data would be to abstract the Cassandra table I'm querying from as a Spark RDD (using `sparklyr` and the `spark-cassandra-connector` with `spark-sql`) and simply doing an inner join on the column of interest (it is a `partition key` column). The company I'm working with says that this approach is a bad idea as it will translate into an `IN` clause in CQL and thus cause a big slow-down.

Instead I'm using their preferred method: write a closure that will extract the data for a single `id` in the `partition key` using a jdbc connection and then apply that closure 200k times for each `id` I'm interested in. I use `spark_apply` to apply that closure in parallel for each executor. I also set my `spark.executor.cores` to 1 so I get a lot of parellelization.

I'm having a lot of trouble with this approach and am wondering what the best practice is. Is it true that Spark SQL does not account for the slowdown associated with pulling multiple `id`s from a partition key column (`IN` operator)?

Answer (score 1):

A few points here:

- Working with Spark-SQL is not always the most performant option, the
  optimized might not always as good of a job than a job you write
  yourself
- Check the logs carefully during your work, always check how your high-level queries are translated to CQL queries. In particular, make sure you avoid a full table scan if you can.
- If you joining on the partition key, you should look into leveraging the methods: **repartitionByCassandraReblica**, and **joinWithCassandraTable**. Have a look at the official doc here: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md and Tip4 of this blog post: https://www.instaclustr.com/cassandra-connector-for-spark-5-tips-for-success/
- Finale note, it's quite common to have 2 Cassandra data center when using Spark. The first one serves regular read / write, the second one is used for running Spark. It's a separation of concern best practice (at the cost of an additional DC of course).

Hope it helps!